# Blender Game Engine Player Flies off When Parented

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

I've been working on this 2D platform game in the BGE, and I'm working on a new feature that will allow the player to jump and grab a rope, and then swing with it.

So how I tried to do that was create logic that set it so that if the player collides with the rope, he is parented to it.

I tried it with the player set to Dynamic physics, and it worked fine. But when I tried it with the player set to Character physics, he flies away.

Personally, I prefer the Character physics, so I really want to use them if I can. So, what's the problem? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Physics objects disable physics when parented.

Basically they are excluded from the Physics Engine calculation as the Parent-Child relationship takes over the transformation processing (position and orientation calculation).

I have the feeling that Character physics is not a really a Physics type and does it's own "magic". It might be that it does not expect the object gets parented to something. This causes a feedback loop and let your object fly away.

Unfortunately I can't really help on this issue directly. maybe you can manually suspend Physics while parenting (see the edit object actuator Mode: Dynamic).